# how to enable fb-login for dynamic subdomains

Tags: javascript, subdomain, fbconnect, facebook-iframe

What is the way(rather the best way) to enable FB-login for dynamic subdomains? Suppose I have domain.com and now my app is self-serve and allow end-user to create their personal app(e.g. myapp.domain.com), where FB-login/registration will be enabled.

how can we have single fb-script to handle this scenario?
Thanks for all the help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is the problem?

If you have set example.com as your domain in your app settings, you should be able to login from *everything*.example.com, no matter what *everything* actually is.

Comment: Aah, thanks! don't know why i was trying with wildcard stuff .